# How to get element by data-... with specified value

Tags: javascript

How to get element by attribute "data-tid" with value of "43574" in Javascript?
There is only one element with this value.

Please avoid using jQuery.

Comment: See here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.querySelector. Give it a try, if you got any problems come back with your code. Help us help you. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In recent browsers you can use

```
var elem = document.querySelector('[data-tid="43574"]')
```

but be warned it's not a fast selector.

To use a variable, do

```
var elem = document.querySelector('[data-tid="'+myValue+'"]')
```

or use

```
var elems = document.querySelectorAll('[data-tid]')
```

and loop over the found elements to check the value.

Comment: May I suggest `querySelector` since it's only one element?

Comment: Ow, and how can I replace 43574 with variable?

Comment: It will probably be faster if you use `querySelector` instead of `querySelectorAll`, since it can stop once it finds the element.

Comment: @MackieeE That sets the attribute, it doesn't search for it.

Comment: @Barmar Nevermind, I see =) Apolgoies! (I know it didn't search for it, I mis-read the comment!)

Comment: I mean, how to do something like this "document.querySelector('[data-tid="VARIABLE"]')", not change the value.

Comment: String concatenation: `'[data-tid="'+VARIABLE+'"]'`